# TinyGPS library doesn't update GPS data when using Arduino ADC

Tags: arduino, gps

I have a problem where I am using [TinyGPS](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/tinygps/) library to get NMEA data from a GPS, while also sampling the ADC at the same time. The problem is that it reads the ADC fine, but it seems to execute the GPS data once, and then the value never changes again. So it will have one value and will never change unless you power off/on the arduino even if you are moving the GPS position will not update.

But, the GPS code by itself works , and the ADC code by itself works perfectly, just when they are combined like below they seem to reset each other or interfere?!

```
#include "TinyGPS.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
TinyGPS gps;

#define RXPIN 10
#define TXPIN 11

SoftwareSerial nss(RXPIN, TXPIN);
const int DATA_COUNT = 50;

// flags

boolean triggered = 0;

// GLOBALS

unsigned  long previousMillis2 = 0;
unsigned long currentMillis2 = 0;
unsigned long start = 0;
unsigned long end_signal = 0;
unsigned long deltaT = 0;
int c = 0;


// GPS variables

unsigned long fix_age, time, date, speed, course;
unsigned long chars;
unsigned short sentences, failed_checksum;
float lat = 0, lon = 0;
double previous_lat = 0;
double previous_long = 0;
float updated_lat = 0;
float updated_long = 0;
float average_lat = 0;
float average_long = 0;
// -------------------

long interval = 20; // interval in milliseconds (10ms => 100Hz)
int data = 0;
float voltage = 0.0;
int THRESHOLD_COUNT = 0;

int start_index = 0;
int jack = 0; 
float THRESHOLD = 0.2;

//CALIBRATION DATA FOR ACCELEROMETER
float one_G = 647.0; // OFFSET OF 1G Z axis
float neg_G = 372.0; // OFFSET OF -1G Z axis
// Our ZERO G Reference should be in the middle of these two readings
float mZ = (one_G + neg_G) / 2.0; // ZERO_G REFERENCE FOR Z AXIS
// Estimate Z axis specific sensitivity difference of 2G between readings
float senZ = (one_G - neg_G) / 2.0;
float sensitivity = 440.0; // FROM DATASHEET TYPICAL SENSIVITIY 440mV/G

float data_window[DATA_COUNT]; // samples held per second 


void ReadAccelerometer();
void count_items();
void get_GPS_data();



void setup()
{
  // The data is sent via the serial port. Initialize it.
  Serial.begin(115200);


  // GPS needs to be at 4800 BAUD

   nss.begin(4800);

   delay(2000);

}


void get_GPS_data()
{
  Serial.println("Entering GPS function");

    while (nss.available())
  { Serial.println("H1");
    c = nss.read();
    if(gps.encode(c));
    {
      Serial.print(c);
      Serial.println("Hi2");


// retrieves +/- lat/long in 100000ths of a degree
gps.f_get_position(&lat, &lon, &fix_age);

// time in hhmmsscc, date in ddmmyy
gps.get_datetime(&date, &time, &fix_age);

// returns speed in 100ths of a knot
speed = gps.speed();

// course in 100ths of a degree
course = gps.course();
//Serial.println(time);
Serial.println("");
Serial.print(lat,4);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print(lon, 4);
Serial.println("");
delay (500);

  }    
}


  Serial.println("Leaving GPS function");
}

int hell = -1; 

void loop()
{

  currentMillis2 = millis(); // Do at 50HZ

   if((currentMillis2 - previousMillis2) > interval) 
   {
      previousMillis2 = currentMillis2;

      ReadAccelerometer(); // Read in voltage 

      data_window[start_index] = voltage; // Fill voltage value into circular 

      // Reset to wrap around the buffer
      if (start_index == DATA_COUNT)
      {
        count_items(); // Call Threshold counting function
        start_index = 0; // Wrap array around

        triggered = false; // reset triggered flag after 1 second

      } else if (start_index == 10) // execute every 1 second....
        {

                    get_GPS_data();

                    previous_lat = lat;
                    previous_long = lon;

                    Serial.println("this should print once a second");
                    hell++;
                    Serial.println(hell);
        }


      start_index++; // Increment Circular buffer running index



  }

  deltaT = THRESHOLD_COUNT * (interval); // Interval needs to be in mS/ DeltaT will be in mS

 if((deltaT >= 60) && (triggered != true)) // Need to find the threshold value 
 {
   triggered = true;

      get_GPS_data();

   Serial.print("CAR HIT");
   Serial.print(lat, 4);
   Serial.print(" Latitude, ");
   Serial.print(lon, 4);
   Serial.print(" Longitude   ");
   Serial.println("");
   Serial.println("");


  THRESHOLD_COUNT = 0; // Reset counted indexes

 }


 }  
  void count_items()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < DATA_COUNT; i++)
  {
    if(data_window[i] >= THRESHOLD)
    {
      THRESHOLD_COUNT++; // count items greater than threshold
    }

  }
}


void ReadAccelerometer()
{


      // Read values from the ADC converter and send them out the serial port.
      data = analogRead(2); // READ ANALOG PIN 2 100uS
      voltage = ((data) / 1024.0) * 5.0;



}
```

Please see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8624/room-for-zacharoni16-and-angelatlarge) for more information on this.  Quick summary

- Some parts of the program behave unpredictably
- Plenty of available SRAM
- Moving the variables around each other seems to help

Comment: what is `nss`?  I don't see that declaration...

Comment: Also, I would think you'd want to print your serial GPS data as it comes in, and print results of `gps.encode()` to localize the problem better. I suspect that for some reason `encode()` returns false when using `AnalogRead()`. Which Arduino are you using?

Comment: Arduino Mega 2560, nss is just the software serial object for the GPS.

Basically what I am doing is I want to continuously get GPS data, but only print it out when a certain event happens on the ADC.

Comment: @ angelatlarge I updated a complete stripped down version of my code It does enter and leave the GPS function each time, it only prints out Serial.print(c); some GPS data on first power up and then it doesn't print anything at all

Comment: It looks like your code reads the GPS only occasionally, which would seem to make the software serial subject to overflow.  To prevent this, you'll need to read and discard the data when you don't want it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton What do you mean discard it to prevent the overflow, not sure I follow? thanks

Comment: The GPS will keep sending data even when you don't need it, so you will need to have a way to ignore that data, either by consuming and discarding it, or a way to recover from serial buffer overflow and re-establish message synchronization.

Comment: @ChrisStratton ah just not sure how I can discard it, I know I only want to print out the data if triggered = true otherwise ignore it

Comment: Read it and do nothing with the result, or research how to handle and recover from overflow of incoming data in this serial library.

Answer (score 1):

I fond the same issue and the solution is :

once you read the GPS data then close the serial port from which you are reading GPS.

And begin the port just before you want to read GPS data.

One better way of writing code:

Create a dummy port and use Serial.listen() functionality.

Hope it may be helpful!